# What is a "dip" in codenameone?

Tags: codenameone

I have read many times that the dipCount parameter used in methods such as `CN.convertToPixels (float dipCount)`refers to the number of **physical millimeters** to convert to pixels, depending on the density of the screen.

However, the javadoc mentions says that dipCount is

> The dips that we will convert to pixels

, which is actually trivial. But the thing is, a "dip" (Density Independent Pixel), or "dp" is universaly known to represent the physical size of a pixel on a 160 dpi screen. That would mean that 1dip = 1 inch / 160 = 25.4mm / 160 =~ 0.16mm , and not "roughly 1mm" as mentioned earlier.

So, in the end, do the `int` parameters named `dipCount` actually represents ~1mm? And if yes, why using that name? Did I think anything wrong?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was written when dips were very different for each platform and had a different definition on Windows desktops than on Android. So we also created a different definition of millimeter. As the years went by we focused on the term millimeter to avoid confusion but that initial constant remained and is still used interchangeably in the code.

So in Codename One DIP == millimeter. Which means 0.159mm == 1 Android DP.